# Undefined Index after posting form to server and saving user_id to $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I am basically a beginner in PHP. I have the basic understanding of it but am really struggling to find a solution to this.

**HomePage.php:**

```
<?php 

 require('dbconnection.php'); 

 if(isset($_POST)&&(sizeof($_POST)>0))
 {
    $sql_query_insert_user = "insert into users(user_fname,user_mname,user_lname,user_dob,user_email,user_doc,user_gender,user_nationality) values '$fname','$mname','$lname','$dob','$email','$doc','$gender','$nationality')";

    mysql_query($sql_query_insert_user,$dbconnect) or die("cannot insert to user");

    $user_id = mysql_insert_id();

    session_start();

    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;

    $sql_query_insert_user_login = "insert into users_login(user_id,user_name,user_password) values ('$user_id','$user_name','$user_password')";

    mysql_query($sql_query_insert_user_login,$dbconnect) or die("cannot connect to user login");

 }


?>
```

And I try to access the session variable like so:

**UserHome.php**

```
<?php 

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['id'];
echo $_SESSION['user_name'];

?>
```

It displays:

> Notice: Undefined index: id Notice: Undefined index: user_name

Any ideas on this error? I've spent ages trying to find out whats going wrong.

Comment: Very sorry i dint know how to enter my code.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;` and then referencing `$_SESSION['id']`. It needs the `user_` prefix.

That bug aside, you need to make sure you're using `method="post"` in your `<form>` tag or that `if (isset($_POST...` block won't get executed, and your session vars will never get set.

When all that is working, stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated and the community has migrated to PDO and similar alternatives like MySQLi for some time now.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I have actually made the corrections and also checked the things u hav mentioned but i still get the error as above. it works if i assign a value to $_SESSION but when i put it inside d if(isset($_POST)) it doesnt assign to it or may be m missing sumthng. can u please tell me.

Comment: `<form name="register" action="UserHome.php" method="post" >`. redirecting to UserHome.php directly after posting the form to server.